# reading k&r(c book) and confusing 1st chapter code

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* copy input to output; 2nd version*/
main()
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
        putchar(c);
}
```

this is very confusing... since you never escape the while loop. I've learned that EOF is -1. i type -1 but it just reprints it. It's a never ending loop. Over time did the library get changed and differs from what the book intended it to be? when i say library i mean the putchar()/getchar() that's in the library... sorry.

Comment: This belongs on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 11):

**How EOF(end of file ) works?**

EOF is simply a macro designating a negative value. It doesn't have to be -1. You can signal end-of-file from the command line with a control character, usually a combination of ctrl+z for Windows systems or ctrl+d for POSIX systems.

*when you write '-1', you do not write the VALUE -1, but the character string { '-', '1' }*

take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file).

Answer (score 2):

**`EOF` is not a character**

This is important. Remember it.

When you try to get a character, several things may happen. The usual is to effectively read a character: your program receives that character and goes on its way ...

```
int ch = getchar();
```

but, what happens is the disk crashes? or there's a bad sector just at that point? or the network goes down? or there is no more data?
Well, then there must be a way to differentiate these **conditions** from plain characters. The way chosen by `C` is to return a value that can **NEVER** be interpreted as a real character. That value is `EOF`, which is a negative value (all real characters are returned with their value converted to `unsigned char` even if your implementation uses `signed char` for `char`). That is also why it is **very important** to use `int` for characters (not `char` as would be expected).

So `EOF` means that it was impossible to read a character. You can try to figure out why (network down? bad sector? end of file? ...) or simply assume it was end-of-file and go from there.

So, in

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

there are two things: an assignment and a comparison

```
c = getchar()
```

will put a value of 0 or more in c for real characters or `EOF` if there's an error, therefore

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
```

means "while there is no error getting characters into variable `c`"

Important thing to remember:

**`EOF` is not a character**. Define characters with `int`.

Answer (score 0):

After entering text, hit the Enter key for a new line.  Then hold down Ctrl and press the letter D.

I'm working on the same book.  I think you should be able to just hit Ctrl+D to exit, but I had to hit Enter first (I think there is something wrong with my shell).

That's in the chapter text, by the way.

Comment: If you hit Ctrl-D twice, the terminal (not the shell) will signal EOF to the program.