# Why is `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` the common idiom?

Tags: c, loops, idioms

Why is

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
   // stuff
}
```

more common/preferred/considered better than the following?

```
ch = getchar();
while (ch != EOF) {
    // stuff
    ch = getchar();
}
```

I can think of some reasons for and against.

For:

- Shorter.
- Everything is done in the condition.
- Can't forget to rewrite the condition before the loop and at the end
  of the loop.

Against:

- Confusing.
- An assignment in a loop (confusing? Messy?).
- A potentially uninitialised variable in the loop's condition (it gets
  assigned, but this may not be immediately obvious).
- Comparison and assignment are kept neatly separated maintaining a
  "one line, one task" mentality in the second format.
- For every assignment there will be one comparison, so the complexity
  in both cases will be the same, hence the easier to understand form
  should be preferred.

Are there other examples where a similar structure is used?

I have the feeling that this question will elicit opinions, so I would ask that they be backed up with some sort of reason. A cursory search revealed no duplicates to this question, so I hope it's not a duplicate!

Comment: I think a better way would be `for(ch = getchar(); ch != EOF;ch = getchar())`

Comment: I'd use for(ch=getchar(); ch != EOF; ch=getchar()) instead of the second case EDIT: ^^ Took the words out of my mouth

Comment: The reason that your alternate form is not used is due to the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). That also applies to the `for` loop solution that seems to be popular today.

Comment: The standard idiom is simply cleaner and clearer than repeating the `getchar` call as in the for-loop solution.

Comment: The 2 choices of the post omit the declaration of `ch`, which is unfortunate as 1) it should be `int` rather than the common error of `char` 2) It does not demonstrate the scoping of `ch` that is often a consideration of writing a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you show is common because it was put forth in the seminal K&R C book.  You can see an example of a novice programmer confused by it right here: [reading k&r(c book) and confusing 1st chapter code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260181/reading-krc-book-and-confusing-1st-chapter-code)

My personal preference is either that way, or this:

```
for (int ch = getchar(); ch != EOF; ch = getchar())
```

Or this:

```
for (int ch; (ch = getchar()) != EOF; )
```

There are lots of ways to skin the cat.  But K&R skinned it first.

Comment: Do you have any idea why they proposed that particular form though? Presumably, it was due to memory constraints and wanting to be as succinct as possible with their code.

Comment: The `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` only expands the macro form of `getchar()` once, rather than a couple of times; it is preferable.

Comment: @jamesh625 Because when the K&R book was written, the authors did not yet know a single thing about what makes good programming practice and readable code. Industry de facto standards for proper program design and readable code had not yet settled. The book was written in the mid 70s, it is ancient and completely outdated.